# AngularJS Cannot read property 'otherwise' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am brand new to Angular, I'm working through a tutorial and I've run into an error when trying to set a default route.  The error is Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module productManagement due to:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'otherwise' of undefined.  My code is below.

```
(function () {
"use strict";
var app = angular.module("productManagement", ["common.services", "ui.router", "productResourceMock"]);

app.config(["$stateProvider",
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/products');
        $stateProvider
        .state("productList", {
            url: "/products",
            templateUrl: "app/products/productListView.html",
            controller: "ProductListCtrl as vm"
        })
    }]

    );
}());
```

Can anyone help a newbie out?

Comment: This would suggest to me `$urlRouterProvider` is undefined, hence why you cannot ready the property `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(...`. Other than this i can be of no help though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your injector array is missing the `$urlRouterProvider`. All dependencies must be listed there.

```
app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider",
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      ...
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you @Anid that was the problem.

Comment: If you want to know why this is done I'd read the 'Dependency Annotation' section on this AngularJS documentation page on Dependency Injection: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di  .